# How to include an image in a box html

Tags: html, css, image

I'm working on a page in html. I was able to include an image in a box but I don't know why it is not visible. Should I have to include it somewhere? It is in the directory with all the others images of the project. Here is the view in my page[image]

And here is my code:

HTML

```
    <div id="LibraryContent"style="text-align:center;">
        <div id="adbox">
            <img src="../images/thriller.jpg" align="left" style="width:100px;height:100px" />
        </div>
    <section class="container">
        <nav>
        <style>
            div {

                height: 650px;
                width: 850px;
                padding: 3px;
                border: 3px solid;
                vertical-align: middle;

            }

        </style>
    </nav>
</section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#LibraryContent {
    background: transparent;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 8px 0 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -300px;
}

#adbox {
    width: 840px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    background-color: dimgrey;
}
```

As I had some problem posting the code I take away the body part. Hope you can help me. It is just a bug or maybe something with the type of the image. All the images are in the directory ../Web/Music/images. I'm not using javascript (just to be precise)

Comment: _All the images are in the directory `../Web/Music/images`_ and yet your looking in `../images/thriller.jpg`

Comment: what is the path of your HTML page?

Comment: check your relative path to image or.make it absolte.

Comment: for all the project I used the same path, ../images/nameOfTheFile and it works. This was for the background, the icons and so on

Comment: Thanks to all guys I solved my problem also with your help

Comment: background are used in css file, if css file is in a folder then file path not necessarily same for html file

Comment: Ok. Now I understand the problem. That's good to know. Thank you very much Himanshu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the above shown image the problem is related to the path

1. try to check that the path is correct or not
2. check that the file type you used is correct or not
3. check the case of file  like you used thriller.jpg instead of Thriller.jpg

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. As I saw for the images I want to use I don't need to go to the previous directory. So instead of ../images/name I have to use only images/name (that's the answer for those who will have the same problem). Thanks hinanshu

Comment: i just posted the same comment just now :)

Comment: It's a good thing to know. Best himanshu. Hope that it will help also other people